# My code is not working in selenium, help required

Tags: java, selenium, automation

There are 2 fields Address and Billing Address both fields throw suggestions.

my code is fine if I comment on the Address code the billing address code is working.
If I comment on the billing address code the address code is working.
but unable to run it when I comment out everything you know anything about this? The code is below.

```
 //adding address and select from the suggestion bar here I'm selecting with ID
          driver.findElement(By.id("entityAddress_0")).sendKeys("Khalifa city sector 13");
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
         List <WebElement> suggestion = driver.findElements(By.className("pac-item")); //here I print all the value which are coming 
         
       //here I'm using for each loop and print the value so we can see all the value which appeared in suggestions
         for (WebElement suggest : suggestion) {
              if(suggest.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Sector 13Khalifa City - Abu Dhabi - United Arab Emirates")) {
                  suggest.click();
              break;
          }
              
              Thread.sleep(1000);
              
              //now adding the billing address
             driver.findElement(By.id("entityAddress_01")).sendKeys("Khalifa city sector 13");
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            List <WebElement> suggestions =driver.findElements(By.className("pac-item-query"));
            for (WebElement suggests : suggestions) {
                //System.out.println(suggests.getText());
                if(suggests.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Khalifa city"));
                suggests.click();
                
            }
    }}}
```

Comment: Please always describe current and desired behaviour and include stacktrace and page source code or url.

Comment: Starting ChromeDriver 94.0.4606.61 (418b78f5838ed0b1c69bb4e51ea0252171854915-refs/branch-heads/4606@{#1204}) on port 45380
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Oct 13, 2021 11:50:46 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

 the code is not working when I comment out the above code then it's work. when I want to complete the flow and comment out the code then it stops.

Comment: If an answer helped you, please select it.

Answer (score 2):

You've got a java error when you declare `suggestions` twice.

You can't declare `List <WebElement> suggestions = driver.findElement();` twice. You can do your first declaration but for your second one, the billing one, you need to remove `List <WebElement>` and just do `suggestions = driver.findElement(//your xpath)` for the second declaration

The two different `suggestions` declarations should look exactly like this:

```
List <WebElement> suggestions = driver.findElements(By.className("pac-item"));
```

and

```
suggestions = driver.findElements(By.className("pac-item-query"))
```